# jQuery change background-color CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-color

Why doesn't the background color change using the following code?:

```
if ($(".enteredCodeDisplay_1").css("background-color") == "rgb(255, 255, 255)" ) {

    alert ("hi");
    $("enteredCodeDisplay_1").css("background-color", "rgb(235, 46, 34)");

}
```

Note: i do get the alert and the if statement doesn't run when the color is not rgb(255, 255, 255)

Comment: Probably because the browser is returning RGBA, and this is generally a bad idea, as different browsers can return different color formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing  `.` on selector class

should be

```
$(".enteredCodeDisplay_1")
```

instead of

```
$("enteredCodeDisplay_1")
```